# Appears default JButton when button looses focus

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, lost-focus

Button lost focus:
[image]
Button has focus:
[image]

Short code:

```
MLibrary = new JButton();
MenuPane.add(MLibrary, new AnchorConstraint(0, 0, 0, 0, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_NONE, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS));
MLibrary.setText("Library");
setButtonDefaults(MLibrary);

MScheduler = new JButton();
MenuPane.add(MScheduler, new AnchorConstraint(0, 0, 0, 110, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_NONE, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS, AnchorConstraint.ANCHOR_ABS));
MScheduler.setText("Scheduler");
setButtonDefaults(MScheduler);

private void setButtonDefaults(JButton but) { //calls in JPanel init only for setting button defaults
    but.setBorderPainted(false);
    but.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    but.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    but.setName(but.getText().toLowerCase());
    but.setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
    but.addActionListener(this);
}

private void enableOnlyOne(JButton but) {//calls each time when one of menu buttons are pressed. but is pressed button
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setButtonDisabled(MLibrary);
    setButtonDisabled(MScheduler);
    setButtonDisabled(MBudget);
    setButtonDisabled(MReports);
    setButtonDisabled(MManage);
    setButtonDisabled(MSettings);
    //enable one
    //but.setFocusPainted(true);
    but.getModel().setPressed(true);
    but.setBackground(ContentPane.getBackground());
    but.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}

private void setButtonDisabled(JButton but) { //sets button unpressed
    but.getModel().setPressed(false);
    but.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    but.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

So, my question is how to code each button, when button looses focus, it would be with light grey background, not default appearance

Comment: @AndrewThompson What is PLAF?

Comment: @PooLaS : LAF stands for Look And Feel, cann't say what P stands for :-)  Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a **Focus Listener** to each button and implement the function `public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)` and inside thie function set the background of the buttons.

**Source:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html

**UPDATE:**

Inside the `focusLost(FocusEvent e)`, put the following code:

```
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
e.setBackground(Color.Gray);
```

Comment: @PooLaS : inside your focusLost Method do this. JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource(); if (button == MLibrary) {Mlibrary.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);} else if (button == MScheduler){MScheduler.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);} Hope that might can help.

Comment: Just one question, why did you put the **if statement** if on **if** and **else** you do the same work?

Comment: @AdelBoutros `e.getComponent().setBackground(ContentPane.getBackground());` I used this to set background, but I can't reach ContentPane because it is outside FocusListener. How can I reach this? ContentPane is jpanel below main menu. This time I try to make same color button and contentPane background, so it looks like tab button

Comment: @Adel Boutros : Exactly, seems like my brain is stuck today, hehe. He can write inside his focusLost method simply this. e.getSource().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); And everything will work. LOL, MY BAD, seems like i shouldn't answer anyone today.  Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali you can't just write `e.getSource().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);`. I tried it first (before your post) and eclipse didn't let me, so I changed it to `e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GREY);`

Comment: @PooLaS : I am really not myself today, just see Adel Boutros's edit, use that, simply replace e with button, i.e. button.setBackground(Color.LLIGHT_GRAY);   r

Comment: Check this link for the difference between **getComponent** and **getSource** (http://www.coderanch.com/t/196784/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/getSource-vs-getComponent)

Comment: Looks like everything working and Adel Boutros answer is good, but strange thing happens. When I tried to log what color returns `ContentPane.getBackground()`, it says 238 238 238. It also return that if i call log inside FocusListener. But if I try to put that color directly to setting background in focuslost and focusgained functions (`e.getComponent().setBackground(ContentPane.getBackground())`), shows as default JButton, but if i manually set color (`e.getComponent().setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238))`), then it works. Strange and don't know how to fix this

Comment: @AdelBoutros do you have any idea how to fix this (what I mentioned in post before)?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your second problem

Comment: maybe it's better to post it as a 2nd question with the new code you have modified based on my suggestion, then I can maybe help you.

Comment: @AdelBoutros ok, I moved this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788696/seems-like-jpanel-background-isnt-read-in-focuslistener)